# Why doesn't pg_dump include all database SETtings?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to have this included in the script generated by `pg_dump`.

`ALTER DATABASE foo SET plv8.start_proc = 'bar';`

I'm using the following command

`pg_dump -s -n public -d development > foo.sql`

The dump file includes some `SET`tings, but it doesn't include the one above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Database (and also role) settings are stored in [pg_db_role_setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html). Like [pg_database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html), there is only one copy of pg_db_role_setting per cluster. So those settings are not stored in database. They are stored globally.

Try to add `--create` parameter to your command. With this, database create  script will be added at the beginning of the dump file with the configuration.